# Laravel Components: default content in {{ slots }}

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-components

In old-style Laravel blade templated we used to use `@section('section-name')` in the following way:

```html
{{-- h1para.blade.php --}}
<h1>
    @section('heading')
        Heading from Template
    @endsection
</h1>
<p>
    @yield('details')
</p>
```

And then extend that template with:

```html
{{-- content.blade.php --}}
@extends('h1para')

@section('details')
    Content from content page
@endsection
```

In the above, my rendered HTML output would look like the following, because the "missing" `'heading'` section in the extending file means that we default back to the content in the template:

```
<h1>Heading from Template</h1>
<p>Content from content page</p>
```

But in the new components way of doing things, I do:

```html
{{-- .../components/h1para.blade.php --}}
<h1>{{ $heading }}</h1>
<p>{{ $slot }}</p>
```

In case you haven't gathered, the question is: how do I set a default value for a slot's contents, such that if it isn't supplied in the extending component/template, it falls back to that default?

(I've done my searches, but haven't been able to find the same question asked before)

---

##### EDIT:

I should add that I've seen the solution (in the Laravel documentation):

```html
<h1>{{ $heading ?? 'Default Heading Here' }}</h1>
```

But this seems only to be appropriate if the default value is a short easy to manage string.  If the default is a long stream of HTML, then it wouldn't work for my needs.

---

##### EDIT 2:

**Just to reiterate:** the whole point of the question is that the default content could be a long stream of HTML. Solving the problem by passing in a string (be that formatted as HTML or not) wouldn't work for my real-world needs.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is this:

```
{{-- .../component/template.blade.php --}}
<div>
    @if (isset($heading))
        {{ $heading }}
    @else
        <h1>Default Heading<span class="subhead">default subheadin and lots of other html content</span></h1>
    @endif
    <p>{{ $slot }}</p>
</div>
```

It's not super elegant, but I think it's the only solution.  Anyone else have a better answer, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score -1):

If you pass data like:

```
<x-h1para header="<span>Header content</span>">
   <div>Default slot content here</div>
</x-h1para>
```

You can display in your component like:

```
 <div>
    <h1>{!! $heading ?? 'Default Heading Here' !!}</h1>
     {{ $slot }}
 </div>
```

Comment: Please see EDIT in the original question (which I think existed before you posted your answer).  I don't want to pass long streams of HTML content via strings.  That is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.